# Cannot see third hard disk from one of the two other OS on a dual boot system

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, multi-boot

Hi I have a dual boot system with the following set up

```
SSD1 : Win10(work system)
SSD2 : Win10(other system)
SataHD : Formatted for file storage call this files disk
```

I can see the files disk from the 'work system'. ( I formatted it from here)
then I reboot into the 'other system'
I cannot see it from the 'other system'

both use the same window 10.

I thought it may be the way the cables are connected to the disks
here is how they are connected....

```
|
-work system
|
-other system
|
-Files disk
```

I want to see the files disk from both systems
any idea why I cannot?

searching for new devices in device manager will not find it.
all drivers are up to date on both systems

Answer (score -1):

cable issue.
for some reason it would work in one system and no the other
unplugging and reconnecting sorted it....